# Calling variables from inside functions in Python

Tags: python, function

I know I have already asked a question like this before but I have made my code much cleaner and I am still coming up with a problem.

My code goes like this:

```
    class Email_Stuff:
        def Get_From_Email():
            #code to open up window and get email address
            emailaddr = #the input
            return emailaddr
        def Get_To_Email():
            #code to open up window and get to email address
            recipaddr = #the input
            return recipaddr
        def Get_Email_Address():
            #code to open up window and get email username
            EmailUser = #the input
            return EmailUser
        def Get_Email_Password():
            #code to open up window and get email password
            EmailPass = #the input
            return EmailPass
        def Send_Email():
            import smtplib
            server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
            server.login((EmailUser),(EmailPass))
            message = "Python Test Email"
            server.sendmail(emailaddr,recipaddr,message)
```

I need to get the variables: `emailaddr`, `recipaddr`, `EmailUser`, and `EmailPass` into the function `Send_Email`. I'm not sure how I could do that though because when I run this code, it tells me that "the global name isn't defined".

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you intend the methods to be static?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make emailaddr, recipaddr, EmailUser, and EmailPass become instance variables by adding prefix "self.".

```
class Email_Stuff():
    def Get_From_Email(self):
        #code to open up window and get email address
        self.emailaddr = #the input
    def Get_To_Email(self):
        #code to open up window and get to email address
        self.recipaddr = #the input
    def Get_Email_Address(self):
        #code to open up window and get email username
        self.EmailUser = #the input
    def Get_Email_Password(self):
        #code to open up window and get email password
        self.EmailPass = #the input
    def Send_Email(self):
        import smtplib
        server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
        server.login((self.EmailUser),(self.EmailPass))
        message = "Python Test Email"
        server.sendmail(self.emailaddr,self.recipaddr,self.message)

instance = Email_Stuff()
instance.Get_From_Email()
instance.Get_To_Email()
instance.Get_Email_Address()
instance.Get_Email_Password()
instance.Send_Email()
```

BTW, name of methods should be lowercase.

Comment: ok i tried this and now I am getting this error message: TypeError: Get_From_Email() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Comment: be careful. Send_Email has a param 'self'.

Comment: And `Send_Email` must be called by an instance. You can new an instance by `instance = Email_Staff()`

Comment: where would I put that @LeeWong

Comment: is there any way to hook this code up to a button so that it would run as soon as I run the application?

Comment: you can put those `instance` codes into your button callback method.

Answer (score 0):

First, if you want these functions to methods associated with an instance of this class, then each method will need a reference to the instance itself as the first argument, usually designated as `self`, though you can name it anything you like.

For example:

```
 def Get_Email_Password(self):
    #code to open up window and get email password
    EmailPass = #the input
    return EmailPass
```

Next, you have two options to get the values ready for `sendmail`.  You can either call each method from within the `Send_Email` method and store the returned values for each one.  That would look like this:

```
def Send_Email(self):
    emailaddr = self.Get_For_Email()
    recipaddr = self.Get_Email_Address()
    ...
```

Or you can store the values, instead of returning them, as instance variables.  So, you would have something like this:

```
 def Get_Email_Password(self):
    #code to open up window and get email password
    EmailPass = #the input
    self.emailaddr = EmailPass
```

And then, in your `Send_Email` method, you would reference the instance variables you have saved:

```
def Send_Email(self):
    ...
    server.sendmail(self.emailaddr, self.recipaddr, self.message)
```

How you choose to do it is up to you, but I prefer the first way.  I also suggest you read up on [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)